# Where do methods of an object go in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

SO, this is what I have:

I have a model which stores the lat and lng of a geographical location, call it location with its own database and table.

```
public class location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int lat { get; set; }
    public int lng { get; set; }

}
```

and I want a method in the line of:

```
   function getDistance(location l){
       return Math.sqrt(l.lat - this.lat).... etc etc.
   }
```

Where should this go? Probably not model? 
Does it belong to control? 
Since it's pretty universal, should make a control that is not associated with a view?

If you could suggest some reading, that would be nice too....

Thanks for the advice(s) in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, do what you want, it's your code, make your own mistakes, think about why things aren't working or are working for your problem domain.

But, typically.

If your object is a **View** then a common practice is to use a **POCO** (Plain old C#/CLR Object), that is a class that only has properties that you want to bind with your display. You can have as many views of the same model(s) as you like depending on your situation. But they don't normally include any logic.

EDIT:

The **Model** is where all your business logic goes. The thing with the frameworks people are using is that it encourages the building of **CRUD** applications which essentially are just an access database on the web. Your **Model** is not just the entity map to your database. Your **Model** may use some form of persistence but it isn't necessarily the only activity it performs.

The **Controller** coordinates action between the ***client*** and the **Model**. In MVC an operation might ask the **Controller** for another page of data. It's the **Controller's** responsibility the ask the **Model** (or a cache, security framework or anything else) to return the required information it needs to ***compose*** the **View** (the answer) to the question posed to the controller.

Comment: So, are you suggesting to let Control handle all logic? 
Or create a service layer??????

Comment: The controller has the responsibility of coordinating calls between the view and the model. The model typically contains your business logic. The model does all your math, persistence and business workflow. The view is simply a point in time view of model state. the controller tells the view what state the model is in. You can have view logic in your view e.g. stuff that might deal with paging. You don't want business logic anywhere but your model.

Answer (score 1):

Putting it in the model would be just fine.

```
public class location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int lat { get; set; }
    public int lng { get; set; }

    public double? getDistance(location l)
    {   
        if (l != null)
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(l.lat - this.lat).... etc etc.
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This will return the distance from one instance of `location` to another.

I know it isn't part of your question, but I think it's important to mention: it's pretty standard convention to capitalize the first letter of a class and method definition.

Comment: This will work, but it is kind of bizzare depending on the use of the object. For model binding I prefer using POCOs for clarity, and then a static class or extension method for operations. Its just a personal preference though, it all depends on the overall design of your app. Also don't forget a null check :)

Comment: @YishaiGalatzer very good point about the null check, thank you. I thought about making a static class, but I decided to do it this way. Personally, I would have said Location.DistanceFrom(Location l) - that makes the most sense to me. But I completely agree - depends on the overall design. Thanks!

Comment: extension method lets you do that. so it will still be location.DistanceFrom(anotherLocation), but it will not appear on the model itself. Really a matter of taste

Comment: @YishaiGalatzer: Thank you for your advice. 
So, by POCO, you mean do: (in psudo code)? 
    `public smartlocation extends location { public double getDist(){.....} }`

Comment: POCO traditionally stands for Plain Old CLR Object. More details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object

Comment: What Johnny says. Basically an object with just automatic get/set properties (though this means even less than the strict definition of POCO)